# Hyperledger/fabric Endorsement policy for one organisation with 5 peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have developed the network for one organisation with 5 peers using nodejs application
but i am bit confused with endorsement policy. I want atleast 3 peers to endorse the the transaction. how should i define if atleast 3 peers have to endorse the transaction.

This is how i am trying to do but its failing. while invoke. can someone please help me with it,

```json
'endorsement-policy': {
    identities: [
       { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: 'Org1MSP' } },
    ],
    policy: {
        '1-of': [ 
            { 'signed-by': 0 }
        ]
   }
}
```

But the above approach doesnt really work for me. can someone please suggest over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to [write your own endorsement plugin](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/pluggable_endorsement_and_validation.html), the lowest granularity you can use for endorsement policies in Hyperledger Fabric is organisation. So, for your example to work, each peer would need to be in a separate organisation. Using the `peer` command CLI syntax, the policy would then be something like:

```
OutOf(3, 'Org1.peer', 'Org2.peer', 'Org3.peer', 'Org4.peer', 'Org5.peer')
```

or, in JSON:

```
'endorsement-policy': {
  identities: [
    { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: ORGS['Org1'].mspid }},
    { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: ORGS['Org2'].mspid }},
    { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: ORGS['Org3'].mspid }},
    { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: ORGS['Org4'].mspid }},
    { role: { name: 'peer', mspId: ORGS['Org5'].mspid }}
  ],
  policy: {
    '3-of': [
      { 'signed-by': 0 }, 
      { 'signed-by': 1 }, 
      { 'signed-by': 2 }, 
      { 'signed-by': 3 }, 
      { 'signed-by': 4 }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: HI Paul, Thanks a lot for your quick response. But i do not wish to have 5 org, is there any other way around please.

Comment: I don't think you have any other options. If you don't want multiple orgs, your only other option is to write a custom endorsement plugin. My question to you would be, if it's one organisation, then by definition you control all the peers, so why do you need 3 peers for endorsement?

Comment: Hi Paul, why i want to have at least 50% endorsement is because -"In the case some peer goes down, for block to create only 50% of the peer's endorsement should be enough to create a block". what would you suggest please? do you have any other idea please

Comment: If a peer goes down, as long as other endorsing peers are still active, the transaction should still complete successfully. In your example with 5 peers, if all of them are endorsing peers, then as long as 1 peer is up, the transaction will succeed.

Comment: Great, Yes all peers are endorsing peers.  Then this is how i am giving endorsement policy for your above mentioned statement. is below policy correct if we consider you latest comment(above).'endorsement-policy': {
    identities: [
    { role: { name: 'member', mspId: 'Org1MSP' }}
    ],
    policy: {
    '1-of':[{ 'signed-by': 0 }]
    }
   }

Comment: It looks ok. But if it´s not working, you should be able to omit the policy, and the default policy will be used, which should work fine for your scenario.